# Restore of laravel 4.2 on server - error in exception handler

Tags: apache, laravel, centos, plesk

Bit of desperation here! My server crashed and I'm trying to restore the sites.

I had a backup but for some reason it's just not working. I get an error `Error in exception handler`.

I've found similar questions which require updates to storage folder permissions which I've now done. But this made no change.

I've checked the site settings in Plesk and it's pointing to the public folder.

The log files doesnt really give much away apart from saying files do not exist:

```
[Wed Aug 17 09:10:22 2016] [error] [client 86.140.200.168] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/XXXX.co.uk/httpdocs/img, referer:     http://www.XXXX.co.uk/
[Wed Aug 17 09:10:22 2016] [error] [client 86.140.200.168] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/XXXX.co.uk/httpdocs/img, referer: http://www.XXXX.co.uk/css/style.css
[Wed Aug 17 09:10:46 2016] [error] [client 157.55.39.248] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/XXXX.co.uk/httpdocs/articles
```

I've had this working without trouble but struggling to find what's wrong with the set up or server config.

The laravel version is 4.2
Centos 6.5
Plesk 12

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Go to /app/config/app.php
Change 'debug' => false to true

Then it will provide more info

Comment: Yep - your right! The debug messages helped - it was missing one of the databases - thought i'd restored but hadn't. I assumed the error was server config rather than app related.